# Can I submit more than 3 reference letters with my grad school applications?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, united-states

Is it acceptable to attach additional reference letters to an application under the supporting documents category of an application? Say I have 3 references from my masters institution, and another 2 from my undergraduate institution. I would think that if they are all positive, that the more is better. Would this be acceptable or is it a no-no? I am particularly thinking about top-10 universities.

Comment: top 10 universities where?

Comment: US universities.

Comment: @GHP: Other schools explicitly tell you not to submit anything beyond what's required. So don't shoot yourself in the foot by not following directions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No!

US institutions expect that you have never seen your recommendation letters; your references are supposed to upload/submit them directly to your target departments.  But presumably you are uploading/submitting your own supporting documents.

If the application web site somehow restricts you to naming only three references, then you only get three letters; choose wisely.  If it's a paper application, just ask all your references to mail in their letters.

(I assume you are applying to a graduate program.)

Comment: Moreover, many schools now no longer __allow__ additional recommendation letters. If they ask for three, they want three, no more, no less. Four is not allowed, and five is right out.